# Why the array seem leaks after I should malloc enough space?

Tags: arrays, c, lapack, intel-mkl

I'm trying to use mkl to compute a equation. But it seem that the array a[] leaks all the time lik this:

```
  44.62  -0.09 -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.00 -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.00 -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.00
  -0.09  11.29  -0.09 -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.00 -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.00
 -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.00  -0.09   0.18  -0.09 -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.00
 -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.00 -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.00  -0.09  11.29  -0.09
 -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.00 -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.00 -6277438562204192487878988888393020692503707483087375482269988814848.00  -0.09  44.62
```

And my code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mkl_lapacke.h"

/* Auxiliary routines prototypes */
extern void my_print_matrix(char* desc, MKL_INT m, MKL_INT n, double* a, MKL_INT lda, FILE* fpWrite);
extern void print_matrix(char* desc, MKL_INT m, MKL_INT n, double* a, MKL_INT lda);

/* Parameters */
#define N 5//nstep
#define LDA N
#define RMIN -10.0
#define RMAX 10.0
/* Main program */
int main() {
    /* Locals */
    MKL_INT n = N, lda = LDA, info;

    /* Local arrays */
    double h = (RMAX - RMIN) / (double(N) + 1.0);;
    double xi;
    double *w;
    double *a;

    w= (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
    a = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * N*LDA);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        xi = RMIN + double(1.0+i) * h;
        a[i*(N+1)] = 2.0 / h / h+xi * xi;
        if (i==0) {
            a[1] = -1.0 / h / h;
        }
        else if (i == N - 1) {
            a[LDA * N-2] =- 1.0 / h / h;
        }
        else {
            a[i *(N + 1)+1] = -1.0/h/h;
            a[i * (N + 1) - 1] = -1.0/h/h;
        }
    }
    print_matrix("Matrix", n, n, a, lda);
    /* Executable statements */
    printf("LAPACKE_dsyev (row-major, high-level) Example Program Results\n");
    /* Solve eigenproblem */
    info = LAPACKE_dsyev(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'V', 'U', n, a, lda, w);
    /* Check for convergence */
    if (info > 0) {
        printf("The algorithm failed to compute eigenvalues.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    exit(0);
} /* End of LAPACKE_dsyev Example */

/* Auxiliary routine: printing a matrix */
void print_matrix(char* desc, MKL_INT m, MKL_INT n, double* a, MKL_INT lda) {
    MKL_INT i, j;
    printf("\n %s\n", desc);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) printf(" %6.2f", a[i * lda + j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The first two elements is seem right but wrong numbers... And the last numbers are a same but very large number. I think it's array leaking,but I don't know how to deal with it. So I ask for help.

And the a[] show is just initialzed,not the result. My problem where is initializing wrong?

Comment: On an unrelated note, the result of `1.0+i` already is a `double`, you don't need the cast.

Comment: Please assume that I am blind and that my screen reader cannot interpret your picture. Does it show a picture of text?

Comment: `w= malloc(sizeof(*w) * N);` <- Much better

Comment: As for your problem, start with a smaller input set, and use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. And I also suggest you store the result of *all* expressions in temporary variables so it's easier to see their values. Then while you step, take note which elements of `a` that you actually initialize. I'll bet you're not initializing all elements properly.

Comment: I dont like `a[i*(N+1)] = 2.0 / h / h+xi * xi;`

Comment: ok,I have show the text. And the a show is just initialzed. I'm sorry for not telling it clearly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's initializing right. But it should not be it...

Comment: @LearningLin Actually no. Please see my answer for why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take a closer look at how you initialize `a`:

```
a[i*(N+1)] = 2.0 / h / h+xi * xi;
if (i==0) {
    a[1] = -1.0 / h / h;
}
else if (i == N - 1) {
    a[LDA * N-2] =- 1.0 / h / h;
}
else {
    a[i *(N + 1)+1] = -1.0/h/h;
    a[i * (N + 1) - 1] = -1.0/h/h;
}
```

Lets take the two cases when `i == 0` and `i == 1`:

1. `i == 0`

   Here you first do the unconditional initialization

   ```
   a[i*(N+1)] = 2.0 / h / h+xi * xi;
   ```

   If we calculate the index `i*(N+1)` it's `0*(N+1)` which is `0`. Therefore you will initialize `a[0]`.

   Then you have `if (i==0)` where you initialize `a[1]`.
2. `i == 1`

   First the unconditional initialization of index `i*(N+1)`, which then is `1*(50+1)` which equals `51`. So here you initialize `a[51]`.

   Then the conditions `i==1` and `i == N - 1` are both false, so we end up in the final `else` clause:

   ```
   a[i *(N + 1)+1] = -1.0/h/h;
   a[i * (N + 1) - 1] = -1.0/h/h;
   ```

   The first index `i *(N + 1)+1` will be `1 *(50 + 1)+1` which is `52`. So you initialize `a[52]`.

   The next index `i * (N + 1) - 1` will be `1 * (50 + 1) - 1` which is `50`. So you initialize `a[50]`.

This pattern repeats throughout the loop, with ever higher indexes, but never lower.

That means you will never initialize index `2` to `49`. These elements will have *indeterminate* values, and if you're unlucky one of those values could be trap-values which would lead to *undefined behavior* when using them.

You need to rework your algorithm to initialize *all* elements of the array `a`.

Answer (score 0):

regarding memory leakage - please don't forget to free all already allocated memory for *w and * arrays by calling free(a) and free(w) functions.